# VPN does not load blocked website but IP is changed successfully

Tags: 18.04, vpn, openvpn

My VPN's Don't load any blocked website but my Ip address successfully changed. 
I tried PPTP , OpenVPN , Kerio but nothing help. 
I disabled IPV6

Comment: Which blocked websites? Who blocked them? How is this related to Ubuntu?  Which DNS servers are you using?

Comment: All normal website lice Facebook Twitter and ... my government blocked them. my OS is Ubuntu 18.04